Expected Number of Lattice Points: Volume Based Proof

A cube of side length $\frac{7}{3}$ is dropped into a random place on the 3D
lattice in the coordinate space (a coordinate plane with an extra
dimension), with the sides of the square parallel/perpendicular to the
axes. The expected number of lattice points (points with integer
coordinates) in the interior of the cubes is $\frac{a}{b}$. In simplest terms,
what's $a$ + $b$? (JHMMC Grade 72020 R1/31)

The official solution uses symmetry and independence to calculate: :
$$\left (\frac{1}{3} \cdot 3+\frac{2}{3} \cdot 2\right )^3=\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)^3=\frac{343}{27}$$
Is there a more elegant, (but still precise) way to do this that gets the answer based on a direct appeal to the volume of the space inside the box, and get the answer directly proportional to the volume (without going through the intermediate calculations).
In particular, is there a logical argument that bypasses the calculations done above.

There is such a way, but it uses integration in $\Bbb R^3$, which doesn't seem within the scope of 7th-grade tools.

I understand integration (even though a 7th grader) doesn't. Also, is it possible to think of it as just volume? (As in, can the ideas of integration be used - without actually using integration?)

The definition of the expected value is an integral (in this case it's actually a limit of integrals over larger and larger regions), so for a general non-symmetric object with a particular volume, I don't really see a way of avoiding it.

I am happy to see the integration based approach for non symmetric objects. Although, since it is a cube, isn't it a symmetric object?
